# Where does infinity go in this theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently studying Mobius transformation and i have proved the following: (I formulated this sentence by myself, so if this approach doesn't seem appropriate please suggest me a better formulation)

> Let $z_1,z_2,z_3$ be distinct points in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$
>
> Let $S:\hat{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ be a Mobius transformation.
>
> Define $C=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:CR(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)\in\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}\}$
>
> If $\exists z\in C$ such that $S(z)=\infty$, then $\exists a,p\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $p\neq 0$ and $S(C)=\{a+tp\in\mathbb{C}:t\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{\infty\}$.
>
> If $\forall z\in C, S(z)\neq \infty$, then $\exists (w\in\mathbb{C}\bigwedge\delta>0)$ such that $S(C)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-w|=\delta\}$.

I have proved the set $C$ is either a **circle** or a **line** in the complex plane.

However, the above theorem says nothing about where $S$ takes $\infty$ to.

Where does $\infty$ arrive under $S$?

If $C$ is replaced by $\overline{C}\triangleq \{z\in\hat{\mathbb{C}}:CR(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)\in\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}\}$, does the theorem remain true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform $z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{a+b/z}{c+d/z}$ maps $\infty\mapsto \frac ac$ (with $\infty\mapsto \infty$ understood if $c=0\ne a$).